# SWIFT: Using reference in array instead of copying Object

Tags: arrays, swift, reference, mutable

I use an array of objects. Then I add some of them to another array. But they are copied. So when I change their content the original value remains unchanged.

```
var primary = [fileObj]()

for image in images {
    if image.oldID != 0 && image.priority != noPriority {
        primary.append(image)
    }
}
```

How can I add a reference in the array, so I'm able to change the content directly in the object?

E.g.:

```
primary[2].priority = -1
```

Answer (score 0):

From the given code the only reason this should happen is if `fileObj` is a struct. `struct` instances are copied by value while `class` instances are passed by reference so change `fileObj` to be a class rather than a struct.